# Modular Command-line Application in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have already written a simple python cmd program using the cmd module. However, I would like it to be modular. For Example, there would be a folder named script and any .py that contains a command would add the command to the application. How would I go about that?

NOTE:
I have figured out how to find and load modules that are within a folder using importlib.

Answer (score 1):

First, you must understand how the cmd module works. I would not go into it here but the gist is command is entered, then split up into the actual command itself and its arguments. The command is then searched in the implementation of the cmd module using getattr(). The resulting function returned is then executed. Raises an error if the function(attribute) is not found.

1. Add the list of modules added to a list.

```
lst.append(importlib.importlib.import_module(<module path here>))
```

2. When cmd is finding a command, modify the code to get it to run through the list of imported modules and see if the function/command exists in that module. If so, execute it.

rough code to find func

```
def findfunc(funcname):
    for module in lst:
        if hasattr(<module class where func is stored>, "<funcname>"):
            return getattr(<module class where func is stored>,"<funcname>")
```

However, I will leave my implementation here. It also includes the capability to reload modules(limited to a certain extent) and private commands that do not show up in help or autocomplete(I am using py prompt toolkit). A fair bit of warning, no docs or help in understanding this code as it is only meant for my personal use only. Meaning don't directly copy it and also It was a modification to the python cmd module.

```
import importlib
import os
import string
import sys
import time

from prompt_toolkit import PromptSession
from prompt_toolkit.completion import WordCompleter
from prompt_toolkit.styles import Style

from internal.logger import logger # my logger Implementation, ignore it 

__all__ = ["cli2"]

PROMPT = '>>> '
IDENTCHARS = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '_'
style = Style.from_dict(
    {
        "completion-menu.completion": "bg:#008888 #ffffff",
        "completion-menu.completion.current": "bg:#00aaaa #000000",
        "scrollbar.background": "bg:#88aaaa",
        "scrollbar.button": "bg:#222222",
    }
)


def parse(arg):
    return arg.split()


class Interpreter:
    identchars = IDENTCHARS
    ruler = '='
    lastcmd = ''
    doc_leader = ""
    doc_header = "Available Commands (type help <topic> to get documentation for <topic> ):"
    misc_header = "Miscellaneous help topics:"
    nohelp = "*** No help on %s"
    use_rawinput = 1
    modulelst = []
    internalcmdlst = ["help", "exit", "reload", "listmodules", "listvar"]

    def __init__(self, intro=None, prompt=PROMPT, stdin=None, stdout=None):
        """Instantiate a line-oriented interpreter framework.

        The optional arguments stdin and stdout
        specify alternate input and output file objects; if not specified,
        sys.stdin and sys.stdout are used.

        """
        self.prompt = prompt
        self.intro = intro
        if stdin is not None:
            self.stdin = stdin
        else:
            self.stdin = sys.stdin
        if stdout is not None:
            self.stdout = stdout
        else:
            self.stdout = sys.stdout
        self.cmdqueue = []

    def cmdloop(self):
        self.preloop()
        try:
            if self.intro:
                self.stdout.write(str(self.intro) + "\n")
            stop = None
            while not stop:
                if self.cmdqueue:
                    line = self.cmdqueue.pop(0)
                else:
                    line = self.session.prompt(self.prompt)
                line = self.precmd(line)
                stop = self.onecmd(line)
                stop = self.postcmd(stop, line)
            self.postloop()
        finally:
            pass

    def precmd(self, line):
        """Hook method executed just before the command line is
        interpreted, but after the input prompt is generated and issued.
        """
        # Parse command to argument
        return self.parseline(line)

    def postcmd(self, stop, line):
        """Hook method executed just after a command dispatch is finished."""
        return stop

    def preloop(self):
        """Hook method executed once when the cmdloop() method is called."""
        self.autocommands = [item[3:] for item in self.get_names() if (item[-5:] != '__pvt') and (item[:3] == 'do_')]
        self.session = PromptSession(completer=WordCompleter(self.autocommands, ignore_case=False))

    def postloop(self):
        """Hook method executed once when the cmdloop() method is about to
        return.
        """
        self.autocommands, self.session = None, None

    def parseline(self, line):
        """Parse the line into a command name and a string containing
        the arguments.  Returns a tuple containing (command, args, line).
        'command' and 'args' may be None if the line couldn't be parsed.
        """
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            return None, None, line
        elif line[0] == '?':
            line = 'help ' + line[1:]
        elif line[0] == '!':
            if hasattr(self, 'do_shell'):
                line = 'shell ' + line[1:]
            else:
                return None, None, line
        i, n = 0, len(line)
        while i < n and line[i] in self.identchars: i = i + 1
        cmd, arg = line[:i], line[i:].strip()
        return cmd, arg, line

    def onecmd(self, linecommand):
        """Interpret the argument as though it had been typed in response
        to the prompt.

        This may be overridden, but should not normally need to be;
        see the precmd() and postcmd() methods for useful execution hooks.
        The return value is a flag indicating whether interpretation of
        commands by the interpreter should stop.

        """
        cmd, arg, line = linecommand
        if not line:
            return self.emptyline()
        if cmd is None:
            return self.default(line)
        self.lastcmd = line
        if line == 'EOF':
            self.lastcmd = ''
        if cmd == '':
            return self.default(line)
        if cmd in self.internalcmdlst:
            return self.getfunc(cmd)(arg)
        else:
            try:
                terminalclass, func = self.getfunc(cmd)
            except AttributeError:
                return self.default(line)
            return func(terminalclass, arg)

    def emptyline(self):
        """Called when an empty line is entered in response to the prompt.

        If this method is not overridden, it repeats the last nonempty
        command entered.

        """
        if self.lastcmd:
            return self.onecmd(self.lastcmd)

    def default(self, line):
        """Called on an input line when the command prefix is not recognized.

        If this method is not overridden, it prints an error message and
        returns.

        """
        self.stdout.write('*** Unknown syntax: %s\n' % line.split(" ")[0])

    def get_names(self):
        # This method used to pull in base class attributes
        # at a time dir() didn't do it yet.
        lst = [*dir(self.__class__)]
        for modulejs in self.modulelst:
            terminalclass = getattr(getattr(modulejs["module"], 'cli_helper'), "Terminal")
            lst += dir(terminalclass)
        return lst

    def print_topics(self, header, cmds, maxcol):
        if cmds:
            self.stdout.write("%s\n" % str(header))
            if self.ruler:
                self.stdout.write("%s\n" % str(self.ruler * len(header)))
            self.columnize(cmds, maxcol - 1)
            self.stdout.write("\n")

    def columnize(self, lst, displaywidth=80):
        """Display a list of strings as a compact set of columns.

        Each column is only as wide as necessary.
        Columns are separated by two spaces (one was not legible enough).
        """
        if not lst:
            self.stdout.write("<empty>\n")
            return

        nonstrings = [i for i in range(len(lst))
                      if not isinstance(lst[i], str)]
        if nonstrings:
            raise TypeError("list[i] not a string for i in %s"
                            % ", ".join(map(str, nonstrings)))
        size = len(lst)
        if size == 1:
            self.stdout.write('%s\n' % str(lst[0]))
            return
        # Try every row count from 1 upwards
        for nrows in range(1, len(lst)):
            ncols = (size + nrows - 1) // nrows
            colwidths = []
            totwidth = -2
            for col in range(ncols):
                colwidth = 0
                for row in range(nrows):
                    i = row + nrows * col
                    if i >= size:
                        break
                    x = lst[i]
                    colwidth = max(colwidth, len(x))
                colwidths.append(colwidth)
                totwidth += colwidth + 2
                if totwidth > displaywidth:
                    break
            if totwidth <= displaywidth:
                break
        else:
            nrows = len(lst)
            ncols = 1
            colwidths = [0]
        for row in range(nrows):
            texts = []
            for col in range(ncols):
                i = row + nrows * col
                if i >= size:
                    x = ""
                else:
                    x = lst[i]
                texts.append(x)
            while texts and not texts[-1]:
                del texts[-1]
            for col in range(len(texts)):
                texts[col] = texts[col].ljust(colwidths[col])
            self.stdout.write("%s\n" % str("  ".join(texts)))

    def addmodulesfromdirectory(self, directory):
        try:
            directory_contents = os.listdir(directory)

            for item in directory_contents:
                self.addmodule(os.path.join(directory, item), "".join([directory[2:], ".", item]))
        except OSError as e:
            print("Something Happened\nPlease try again :)")
            logger.error("OSErrot, {}".format(e))
        except ImportError as e:
            print("Something Went Wrong while importing modules\nPlease try again :)")
            logger.error("ImportError, {}".format(e))
        except Exception as e:
            print("Oops, my fault\nPlease try again :)")
            logger.error("Exception, {}".format(e))
        finally:
            logger.info("Done importing cli modules")

    def addmodule(self, pathdir, importdir):
        if os.path.isdir(pathdir):
            importedmodule = importlib.import_module(importdir)
            modulejs = {
                "module": importedmodule,
                "name": importedmodule.__name__,
                "importdir": importdir,
                "pathdir": pathdir
            }
            self.modulelst.append(modulejs)

    def removemodule(self, modulename):
        if modulename in [x["name"] for x in self.modulelst]:
            self.modulelst.remove(self.getmodulejs(modulename))
            del sys.modules[modulename]
        else:
            raise ModuleNotFoundError

    def replacemodule(self, modulename):
        module = self.getmodulejs(modulename)
        self.removemodule(modulename)
        self.addmodule(module["pathdir"], module["importdir"])

    def getmodulejs(self, modulename):
        for i in self.modulelst:
            if i['name'] == modulename:
                return i

    @staticmethod
    def getmoduledep(modulename):
        unsortedscriptsysmodules = [module for module in sys.modules if (("script" in module) and ("script" != module))]
        sortedlst = []
        for scriptmodules in unsortedscriptsysmodules:
            mod = sys.modules[scriptmodules]
            if not (hasattr(mod, "__path__") and getattr(mod, '__file__', None) is None) and (
                    scriptmodules != "script.{}".format(modulename)):
                sortedlst.append(sys.modules[scriptmodules])
        return sortedlst

    def reloadmoduledep(self, modulename):
        for dep in self.getmoduledep(modulename):
            try:
                importlib.reload(dep)
            except ModuleNotFoundError as e:
                print(e)

    def getfunc(self, command):
        if "do_" in command:
            command = command[3:]
        if command in self.internalcmdlst:
            return getattr(self, "_".join(['do', command]))
        else:
            for modulejs in self.modulelst:
                terminalclass = getattr(getattr(modulejs["module"], 'cli_helper'), "Terminal")
                if hasattr(terminalclass, "_".join(['do', command])):
                    return terminalclass, getattr(terminalclass, "_".join(['do', command]))
            raise AttributeError

    def do_help(self, arg):
        """
        List available commands with "help" or detailed help with "help cmd".
        """
        if arg:
            # XXX check arg syntax
            try:
                func = self.getfunc('help_' + arg)
            except AttributeError:
                try:
                    if arg[-5:] == '__pvt':
                        raise AttributeError
                    doc = self.getfunc('do_' + arg).__doc__
                    if doc:
                        self.stdout.write("%s\n" % str(doc))
                        return
                except AttributeError:
                    pass
                self.stdout.write("%s\n" % str(self.nohelp % (arg,)))
                return
            func()
        else:
            names = self.get_names()
            cmds_doc = []
            funchelp = {}
            for name in names:
                if name[:5] == 'help_':
                    funchelp[name[5:]] = 1
            names.sort()
            # There can be duplicates if routines overridden
            prevname = ''
            for name in names:
                if name[:3] == 'do_' and name[-5:] != '__pvt':
                    if name == prevname:
                        continue
                    prevname = name
                    cmd = name[3:]
                    if cmd in funchelp:
                        cmds_doc.append(cmd)
                        del funchelp[cmd]
                    elif self.getfunc(name).__doc__:
                        cmds_doc.append(cmd)
            self.stdout.write("%s\n" % str(self.doc_leader))
            self.print_topics(self.doc_header, cmds_doc, 80)
            self.print_topics(self.misc_header, list(funchelp.keys()), 80)

    def do_exit(self, arg):
        """
        Exit
        """
        if arg:
            print(self.prompt + "No arguments please")
        print("Exiting")
        time.sleep(1)
        return True

    def do_reload(self, arg):
        if arg == "":
            print("No Arguments found")
            return
        arg = parse(arg)
        if arg[0] == "all":
            localmodulelst = self.modulelst.copy()
            self.modulelst = []
            for i in localmodulelst:
                print("Reloading", ".".join(i["name"].split(".")[1:]))
                importlib.invalidate_caches()
                self.reloadmoduledep(i["name"])
                self.addmodule(i["pathdir"], i["importdir"])
            self.autocommands = [item[3:] for item in self.get_names() if
                                 (item[-5:] != '__pvt') and (item[:3] == 'do_')]
            self.session = PromptSession(completer=WordCompleter(self.autocommands, ignore_case=False))
        else:
            print("Only argument \'all\' is accepted")

    def do_listmodules(self, arg):
        arg = parse(arg)
        if arg[0] == "sys":
            for i in sys.modules:
                print(i)
        elif len(arg) != 0:
            print("No Argument Please")
        else:
            print("Listing all imported Modules")
            for i in self.modulelst:
                print(".".join(i["module"].__name__.split(".")[1:]))
```